# push dynamically coming id's and value's in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, push

The question may seem a little confusing so let me explain the situation, i have a category field, that when it's chosen, i get data from api based on that category, for example when you choose category A, you may get the id's 1 to 3 or when you chose category B, you get the id's of 8 to 11, so what i'm trying to do is create a Filter array that pushes these values with id's so when user types something like `sth` in input with the id of 1, this objects gets pushed to the array, something like below:

```
Filters = [ 
   {
     id:1,
     value: sth
   }
]
```

so what i have basically done is something like this:

```
this.props.Filters.map(item => (
     <div className="from" key={item.id} id={item.id} >
          <span className="title">{item.feature}</span>
          <input type="text" placeholder="..." id={item.id} onChange={FilterPush}></input>
     </div>
))
```

and the function is:

```
const Filters = []
const FilterPush = (e) => {
      const filter = {
           id: e.currentTarget.getAttribute("id"),
           value: e.currentTarget.value
       }
       Filters.push(filter)
}
```

the problem i'm having here is every time a user is typing something an object is pushed to `Filters`,
so when user tries to type `sth` the `Filter` gets equal to:

```
Filters={
    {id:1,value:s},
    {id:1,value:st},
    {id:1,value:sth}
}
```

but i want it to be equal to this

```
Filters={
    {id:1, value:sth}
}
```

bear in mind that the id's are dynamic and i don't know them, and there's not just one input, i mean we can have 3 inputs with diffrent id's that should get send to the server.

Comment: so basically what are you trying to achieve is to push the value to `Filter` array when user stop typing,Right?

Comment: yeah, that's what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter out existing id:

```
const FilterPush = (e) => {
      let id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("id")
      const filter = {
           id,
           value: e.currentTarget.value
       }
       Filters = Filters.filter(item => item.id !== id) // filter out existing id
       Filters.push(filter)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple all you have to do is just check the pushing element's id is already in the Filters array before pushing the element.

```
const FilterPush = (e) => {

    let id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("id")
    const filter = {
        id: e.currentTarget.getAttribute("id"),
        value: e.currentTarget.value
     }

     Filters.map(item=>{
         if(id == item.id){

             available = true;

         }
     })
    if(!available){
        Filters.push(filter)

    }
```

}